# Moved my wordpress install to a subfolder and now the pagination doesn't work anymore?

Tags: wordpress, pagination

So I moved a wp install to a subfolder and now the pagination for news section doensn't work anymore (trying out on a local xampp ). I already tried to update  and resave the permalinks.

Is there any general code by which I can check if /news/page/3/ returns new data?

This is the longwave theme part in Template Name: Blog

```
    //Post ID
    global $wp_query;
    $content_array = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
    if(isset($content_array->ID)){
        $post_id = $content_array->ID;
    }
    else $post_id=0;

$template_uri = get_template_directory_uri();

//Page Options
    if(have_posts()) $pageoptions = getOptions($post_id);   

//Theme Options 
    $themeoptions = getThemeOptions(); 

//Page Head Area
    if(isset($pageoptions['tb_longwave_activate_page_title'])){ 
        $headline = false;
    } 
    else {
        $headline = true;
    }

//Default Values
    $align = "";
    //Orientation
    if(empty($pageoptions["tb_longwave_blog_display_type"])) $pageoptions["tb_longwave_blog_display_type"]="left";

    //Posts per Page
    //Default Setting WP
    $posts_per_page = get_option('posts_per_page');
    //Optional Setting Page Options
    if(!empty($pageoptions["tb_longwave_posts_per_page"]))
        $posts_per_page = trim($pageoptions["tb_longwave_posts_per_page"]);
```

and the pagination nav part

```
 if(have_posts()) : 
            //Postcounter is for Linebreaks + Display
                $postcounter = 1;
                while(have_posts()) : the_post();   
                    //Custom Blog WP Query
                    if(!is_front_page())
                        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                    else
                        $paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
                    $args = array('offset'=> 0, 'paged'=>$paged, 'posts_per_page'=>$posts_per_page);
                    $all_posts = new WP_Query($args);
```

I also tried hardcoded

```
$args = array('offset'=> 0, 'paged'=>2, 'posts_per_page'=>8);
                        $all_posts = new WP_Query($args);
```

***EDIT***
Ok I found this code to work:

```
$all_posts = new WP_Query('showwposts='.$posts_per_page.'&paged='.$paged);//<--this work
// $all_posts = new WP_Query($args);//<-- this does not work
```

Answer (score 0):

To move wordpress follow this guide : https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Maybe you have to made changes in your database.

Comment: tx, I am following https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory only problem I see right now is the pagination

Answer (score 0):

Just use this script https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/ and replace all localhost to yourdomain.tld in your database.

Comment: hmm, I am testing on my localhost and on my localhost pagination doesn't even work in a subfolder

Comment: what has replacing the old url -> new url to do with the query posts getting back??

Answer (score 0):

Use the script that Codeartist provided or WP Migrate DB plugin because there can be broken links or serialized data. WP Migrate DB handles serialized data.